# How do we know the model converged while training a neural network for object classification/detection?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I am using Tensorflow's Object Detection API to detect cars. It should detect the cars as one class "car".

I followed sentdex's following series:

https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/

System information:

OS - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

GPU - Nvidia 940M (VRAM : 2GB)

Tensorflow : 1.10

Python - 3.6

CPU - Intel i5

Problem:
The training process runs pretty fine. In order to know when the model converges and when I should stop training, I observe the **loss during the training per step** in the terminal where the training is running and **also observe the Total Loss graph in Tensorboard** via running the following command in another terminal,

```
$tensorboard --logdit="training"
```

But even after training till 60k steps, the loss fluctuates between 2.1 to 1.2. If I stop the training and export the inference graph from the last checkpoint(saved in the training/ folder), it detects cars in some cases and in some it gives false positives.

I also tried running **eval.py** like below,

```
python3 eval.py     --logtostderr     --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config     --checkpoint_dir=training/     --eval_dir=eval/
```

but it gives out an error that indicates that the GPU memory fails to run this script **along with** train.py.

So, I stop the training to make sure the GPU is free and then run **eval.py** but it creates only one eval point in eval/ folder. Why?

Also, how do I understand from the Precision graphs in Tensorboard that the training needs to be stopped?

I could also post screenshots if anyone wants.
Should I keep training till the loss stays on an average around 1?

Thanks.

PS: Added Total Loss graph below till 66k steps.

[image]

PS2: After 2 days training(and still on) this is the total loss graph below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Usually, one uses a separate set of data to measure the error and generalisation abilities of the model. So, one would have the following sets of data to train and evaluate a model:

- **Training set:** The data used to train the model.
- **Validation set:** A separate set of data which will be used to measure the error during training. The data of this set is not used to perform any weight updates.
- **Test set:** This set is used to measure the model's performance after the training.

In your case, you would have to define a separate set of data, the **validation set** and run an evaluation repeadingly after a fixed number of batches/steps and log the error or accuracy. What usually happens is, that the error on that data will decrease in the beginning and increase at a certain point during training. So it's important to keep track of that error and to generate a checkpoint whenever this error is decreases. The checkpoint with the lowest error on your validation data is one that you want to use. This technique is called **Early Stopping**.

The reason why the error increases after a certain point during training is called **Overfitting**. It tells you that the model losses it's ability to generalize to unseen data.

**Edit:**
Here's an example of a training loop with early stopping procedure:

```
 for step in range(1, _MAX_ITER):
     if step % _TEST_ITER == 0:
         sample_count = 0
         while True:
                try:
                    test_data = sess.run(test_batch)
                    test_loss, summary = self._model.loss(sess, test_data[0], self._assign_target(test_data), self._merged_summary)
                    sess.run(self._increment_loss_opt, feed_dict={self._current_loss_pl: test_loss})
                    sample_count += 1
                except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                    score = sess.run(self._avg_batch_loss, feed_dict={self._batch_count_pl: sample_count})
                    best_score =sess.run(self._best_loss)
                    if score < best_score:
                        '''
                        Save your model here...
                        '''
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. How do I repeat the the evaluation? isn't it something which keeps running and shows info when completed? like training that runs on it's own once started?

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. What I do is to visualize the training and validation using tensorboard. In general, my training runs for a fixed amount of batches or epochs and automatically saves the best state to disk. So you can always access the states.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this one.

Comment: You can't just simply copy it. You'll have to define the graph for the calculation yourself.

Comment: Yes I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: Your loss is quite high...of course, depending on your loss function. What’s your loss function?

Comment: I am not sure. I just followed along the tutorial I mentioned above. Used the code. I tried stopping the training and using the last few checkpoints detecting cars.. for some it ran fine but during the live video detection sometimes it mis-detected me as a car. So I wanted to know why is the loss fluctuating between 2-1 and not converging. As from the video he says, get to about a loss of 1 on an average. 
My batch size is 5 as I have only 2GB memory in my graphics card. 
I trained till 100k steps but still it doesn't stay stable around 1-1,2 or so.

Comment: Well that can be caused by many reasons such as learning rate is too high or your batch size is too small. You have to also check your solver.

Comment: My learning rate is 0.004 and batch size is 5, but the batch size can't be increased as the GPU has only 2 GB VRAM and it quits the training if I increase it.

Comment: Do you use Adam or SGD?

Comment: You mean optimizer? I think tensorflows api has SGD.
I added another screenshot of the total loss graph after two days of training. I am really stuck.

Comment: What you can try is, to decrease the learning rate. You could also use a step policy for it. Let's say, you start with a initial learning rate (lr) of 0.0001 and decrease it at every n-th iteration using lr*0.1. An alternative is to use Adam optimizer. But you have to think of the fact that the bach size tells the optimization process the direction to the minimum. 5 is very small and what the learning does, is to oscillate a lot because of the smalls batch size.

Comment: Ok I will try this and let you know what I get. Thank you :)

Comment: I stopped the training randomly at a loss at around 1.2 (which makes actually no sense) and checked the detection performance. Luckily it is working fine i.e. 90% of the cars are detected. This doesn't answer the question though. I just wanted to tell you this. I think I gotta read more about Deep learning and Neural networks. Thank you.

Comment: Very gentle explanation, thank you very much @Bastian